# Using VB 6.0 Forms in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6

Any ideas on how to Use Forms created in VB 6.0 in VB.NET ?

Comment: You ABSOLUTELY can. This is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

1. Put your VB 6 in a DLL.  Create a public method that invokes a modal dialog from VB 6.
2. From your .NET program, reference the DLL built in VB 6 (COM tab)
3. Invoke the method.  Your VB6 modal form will appear.

If you want to show a modeless form, you may be out of luck because VB 6 requires that the caller of the dialog do special processing in the message pump.  However, you may be able to trick the system by trying this: From the VB 6 code, rather than calling the Show method of the VB 6 form, set the .Visible property of the VB 6 modeless form to True.   It will probably work.  Some things may not work such as button shortcuts, and some ActiveX controls embedded in the VB 6 code might have problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try this post:

[Can/how do you host a full VB6 Form in a C# WPF app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239845/can-how-do-you-host-a-full-vb6-form-in-a-c-wpf-app)

Having done this myself several times in the past, let me just say this is not fun stuff.